# Sefarim specifically made for "Daily Hizuk"

Tags: product-recommendation, mussar-ethics

Are there any books/articles/websites/email programs that can help provide a daily Hizuk?

By Hizuk, I mean something gives one more of a mood to be Oved Hashem.

Comment: "[S]end out" seems to go with "email programs" and possibly "websites". How do "books" and "articles" fit in this question?

Comment: @HachamGabriel Bringing Heaven Down To Earth or anything by Tzvi Freeman. Kaleidoscope by Dovid Zaklikowski. From Optimism to Hope by Jonathan Sacks. Or you could go the route of Jews before you and say tehillim :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charlie Harary, [a noted speaker on inspirational Jewish topics](http://charlieharary.com/bio/), said in a talk/Q&A (2/29/2012) at Yeshiva University (in the presence of YU Rosh Yeshivah Rabbi Yaakov Neuburger) that there are three books that give him chizzuk whenever he learns them.
They are:

## 1: Nesivos Shalom,

## 2: Michtav Me'Eliyahu (Rabbi Dessler's Strive for Truth),

## 3: Sifsei Chaim.

Also, I once heard that the two favorite musar sefarim of Rabbi Avigdor Miller ztz"l were:

## 4: Mesillas Yesharim

## 5: Chovos HaLevavos.

Rav Miller was said to have learned these two seforim for hours on end when taking a break from learning Gemara during the time he spent learning in Slabodka.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about R' Miller. It makes sense that he learned something other than Gemara (Shnayim Mikra comes to mind). Do you have a source that these were his favorite Sefarim or that he learned them in Slabodka? Otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

See the [Hayom Yom](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/hayomyom.asp?tDate=2/29/2012) written by the Lubavitcher Rebbe. Short and sweet.

Comment: +1, but I would give it +∞ if I could.

Answer (score 4):

What can be more mechazek than a daf of Gemara? There's a daily Gemara program which learns one daf per day called [Daf Yomi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf_Yomi). Shiurim are easily available on websites such as [DailyGemara.com](http://www.dailygemara.com/) and [YUTorah](http://www.yutorah.org/daf.cfm). Furthermore, since the program is widespread throughout Jewish communities across the globe, you can likely find a Daf Yomi class in your local synagogue or bet midrash.

Comment: What about Hizuk to learn Gemara? See Berachot 32

Comment: ת״ר ארבעה צריכין  חזוק ואלו הן :תורה ומעשים טובים תפ ל ה  ודרך ארץ תורה ומעשים טובים

Comment: Well...I'm referring to Hizuk from Ashekneazi Yeshivot. Got any ideas? You happen to be correct about my interpretation of the Gemara (which I was hoping you wouldn't point out). The actually explanation is different than the way I made it seem.

Comment: Care to use your expertise?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend basically any Breslover seforim. I'm currently enjoying Rabbi Yaakov Meir Shechter's - A Scent of Eden. This sefer is both an educational manual in improving avodas Hashem as well as full of powerful and inspiring Torah to be m'chazek the learned and unlearned alike.

http://www.nehora.com/products/A-Scent-Of-Eden.html

Comment: +1, and I want to mention that this includes any of the seforim that are written by R' Shalom Arush!