# What is a good mussar/personal growth sefer for women?

Tags: women, product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

Most mussar sefarim are very oriented towards men, with lessons on things such as how to treat your wife, the dangers of pursuing women, or the importance of learning. Also, many sefarim I've seen written for women are very generic and watered down hashkafa sefarim, lacking originality or deep insight. What is a good, intelligent, well-written mussar sefer with female perspective?

Comment: AFAICT ibn Pequda's Chovot HalLevavot isn't genderized, but, although it's sold in the "mussar" section of bookstores, it's more of a philosophical work IMO.

Comment: http://www.tziporahheller.com/ Rebbetzen Heller has online classes in Chovot HaLevavot and has written several english language books that might interest you.

Comment: Indeed.  CH is definitely on the philosophical side, which is probably why it is more gender neutral (abstract ideas as opposed to practical daily concepts).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14831/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't disagree, but that's hardly written from a female perspective ;)

Comment: @YaakovKuperman [I beg to differ.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7074/759)

Comment: @DoubleAA , I never said women anything about whether women could/should learn Gemara, I said it's not written from a female perspective.

Answer (score 8):

For English readers there is one from Rabbi Shimshon Pincus who wrote a Mussar Sefer for woman called [Nefesh Chaya.](http://www.feldheim.com/mussar-growth-and-inspiration/self-growth-inspiration/nefesh-chaya.html)

For Hebrew readers there is a [Sefer Chukei HaNoshim](http://www.breslev.co.il/store/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA__%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D.aspx?id=14391&language=hebrew) written by the Ben Ish Chai which is a Mussar Sefer geared specifically to women.

For Yiddish readers there is a [Sefer Mainekes Rivka](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A8) which was written by Rivka Tiktiner in in the late 16th century. This is available by contacting eliezerbrodt@gmail.com

Answer (score 8):

My wife speaks extremely highly of Chochmat Nashim by R' Shalom Arush shlita, which is translated in to English by R' Lazer Brody shlita.  It focuses on marriage and married life, but covers the full spectrum of a woman's role and responsibilities.

Comment: The book is called "Women's Wisdom" in English. I came here to recommend the sefer because I have heard from several ladies that it is good, but you already put it here...a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

Chovos Halevavos. There's a new digital translation in the making, available online at http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=384

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15360/what-is-a-good-mussar-personal-growth-sefer-for-women/18599#comment30342_15360 et seq.

Comment: ray, thanks for the suggestion, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1820/ray), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: (An anonymous user suggested seeing shaar bitachon there. I have not seen it inside, so I can't vouch for it, and with no other information provided I'm deleting it from the answer and moving it to a comment.)

Comment: it looks good to me (shaar bitachon). also has some excerpts from the classic commentators on the book

Answer (score 5):

Outside of the Ashkenazi world, Chakham Yosef Chayyim (the Ben Ish Chai) wrote a beautiful personal growth manual for women, and one that is often studied by men as well. He wrote it in Judeo-Arabic, and called it Qânûn-un-Nisâ'. It has since been translated into Hebrew, as חוקי הנשים, and into English, as *Laws For Women*. The English translation has been done by Rabbi Moshe Schapiro.

Comment: IMHO, this should be folded into the [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15403/2091) above.

Answer (score 1):

Meneket Rivkah was written in Yiddish by a woman, Rivka Bat Meir Tiktiner, in the 1500s and likewise translated by a woman into English in the 2009, more info here: https://www.mussar.center/books/classic#h.dy0hg7ld91ok

Some believe Orchot Tzadikim was written by a woman: https://www.mussar.center/books/popular#h.zdiv4xhkinh9

There are several Mussar books written by women in this list of modern Mussar works too: https://www.mussar.center/books/modern

I hope this helps!